# Complicated: 4 consecutive curls with XML in between

Tags: php, xml, forms, post, curl

I've a tricky question on how to deal with consecutive curls in PHP. I have this incredibile data flow:

1. **example.com/one.php** post data via curl to **another.com/two.php**
2. **another.com/two.php** post data via curl to **another.com/three.php**
3. **another.com/three.php** responds me with XML (or JSON) back to **another.com/two.php**
4. **another.php/two.php** transforms the XML into a php array and then into a query string that i post via curl back to the origin **example.com/one.php**

It works. If you are wondering why i have this insane data flow it's due to the fact that another.com/three.php is an obfuscated file with Ioncube. I can't edit it but i have to add some checks before i can send data to him. Don't waste time trying to figure out how i can make it in an alternative way because there isn't one (trust me).

On example.com/one.php there's a form where users fill in data. When they press "Submit" they remain on this page while "silently" i make 1->2->3->4 to get their response (the $_POST of step 4) then can save it into example.com/log.txt. Again it works.

Now my question is: how can i display the $_POST response (which is the same i get in log.txt file) in example.com/one.php? I mean this is what i have in step 4.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, example.com/one.php);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
```

$_POST arrives on example.com/one.php but of course users and this curl are on two different level. I tryed playing with file_get_contents(), sleep() and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER with no success. What's the answer this this question? I would go for sessions or ob_start() but i'm not sure of it.

Comment: `include` doesn't work for you? It might be tricky to get your super globals in the right state but it's by no means impossible, as you claim.

Comment: What Frits coments makes sense. You can make `another.com/two.php` include `another.com/three.php` and do it with the superglobals. you can capture the output of it with an output buffer. That should streamline the process as well because you have much more "proxied" the obfuscated script so you have more control as with a HTTP request.